# Can not make git pull after import

Tags: python, django, linux, git, repository

I have a problem with the file which is imported (application in django 1.11). After importing the file, the data is saved to it, its status is modified:

```
modified: media/import_file.json
```

Then I want to do a git pull on my code and I can not because the file is modified.
I have entries in the `.gitignore` file, but they do not work:

```
/www/media/import_file.json
/www/media/*
```

Comment: can you share the git error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.gitignore` is only looked up when we add files to repo. So, if the file was already added to git (using `git add`), just putting it in gitignore won't work. 
Once you add the file to .gitignore, you need to exclude it from the repository as well. It can be done using-

```
git rm --cached /www/media/import_file.json
```

Please make sure to add the --cached flag. It ensures that the file is removed from git repository only and not the file system.